# DeleteFile() function returns success, but the file remains undeleted

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm working on a program that tracks actions in a folder and stores them in a text file and replicates the changes on another directory. The program reads the performed actions from `Logfile.txt` and stores the result of the operation in `ProcessLog.txt`

In case of delete operations happening in the folder, the action is stored in `Logfile.txt` as

```
DEL
F:\somefolder\something.txt
```

where a `\n` is present at the end of each line. I'm running this code in another similar directory to automatically delete the file

```
std::ifstream Restfile("F:\\Logfile.txt");
std::ofstream Test("F:\\ProcessLog.txt");
while(!Restfile.eof())
{
    std::string Action;
    std::getline(Restfile, Action);
    if(Action.compare("DEL")==0)
    {
        std::string Directory;
        std::getline(Restfile, Directory);
        //============================
        Test<<"Deleting "<<Directory<<"\n";
        //============================
        std::wstring Directory_wstr( Directory.begin(), Directory.end() );

        if(DeleteFileW(Directory_wstr.c_str()))
            Test<<"Delete Success\n";
        else
            Test<<"Delete failure\n";
     }
}
//proper closing statements
```

I get `Delete Success` stored in `ProcessLog.txt` which means that the function executed successfully, yet the file still remains in the directory withut being deleted

Comment: Probably the file is still opened by other process.  Windows mark it as being deleted, after all handle to the file are closed, it will disappear.

Comment: @TigerHwang I just created the file and didn't even open it. What process would be using it?

Comment: It's complicated, maybe a anti-virus app is scanning the file, or maybe some other system service is watching the files creation.

Comment: @TigerHwang I forgot to close the automatically created handle. Thanks for pointing that out